# Need help configuring CAS authentication in Laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, permissions, cas

I'm writing a PHP web application on Laravel 4 that does user authentication with my university's CAS (Central Authentication Server). I am using this package to do the CAS authentication: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/xavrsl/cas

Here is my configuration file for the CAS authentication: [CAS Config](http://pastebin.com/LbZp17S5)
Here is my 'User' model that is referenced in the CAS Config: [User Model](http://pastebin.com/qfGNfcUu)

My current problem is actually checking the authentication itself after the user has logged in (using a simple check, if isAuthenticated() echo "Authenticated"). Laravel throws this error when trying to use the isAuthenticated function: [Laravel Error](http://pastebin.com/6fS9jWMZ) and [Exception thrown](http://pastebin.com/UYpesMSA).

Background about how the authentication should work: Since no passwords are stored in the application database (just in the CAS), I'm planning on checking the authentication via CAS, and then associating their ULID (university username) with a permission setting using the Entrust package ([Entrust](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/zizaco/entrust)).

Is this a feasible way to do the authentication and then control user permissions? Normally user authentication and permissions wouldn't be such a problem for me, but adding CAS into the equation is just making this a bit tough, especially with me being new to Laravel.

Comment: The actual text of the error message would be useful.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/UYpesMSA

Comment: It seems like there is no $text_response being fed to the loadXML() function.

Comment: Yeah, not really enough context to debug -- laravel's requesting XML from somewhere and getting back a blank string.  Figure out why that's happening and you'll get this particular bug solves.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my problem. I removed the 'User' from the cas_uri in the config and everything works A-OK now.